# Create Task in project using the API on ASANA

Tags: asana

Using the ASANA API, I can't find a way to create an unassigned task attached to a project. Ex: I would like to create a task "Add this feature" to workspace "12345678" and add it to project "456789" without assignee.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

Every project belongs to exactly one workspace, and all tasks in that project must also be in that workspace. Therefore, specifying both project and workspace would be redundant.

That said, if you look at [the Task documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks) you will see you can specify a `projects` array at creation time to indicate which projects the new task should be created in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

It strange because I have 1 workspace, the company name, and 3 projects under it. I tried to put only the workspace, but if I put nothing in assignee, it doesn't show up anywhere. I tried to assign it to me directly and it showed up in the workspace (company name) under "No project"

I like it to appear in "company name" -> "requests" -> unassigned

Thanks

Comment: Right, all tasks belong to zero or more projects, and either have or do not have an assignee. Creating a task without a project or assignee is possible, but often not useful - how should one find it? In the Asana UI you are by default looking at tasks assigned to you, not "all tasks" (there is no view for "all tasks" - it would be too large!) Try specifying just the project you want (the id for "requests") and it should end up in the place you want.

Comment: I believe this answer is now out of date. Tasks can be created in a workspace with multiple projects per the [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks).